# How to combine argo workflow with argo cd?

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argocd

I would like to deploy [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) on my K8S cluster. In addition, the prerequisite for using Keycloack is a database, so I am going to use postgresql.

Before deploying Keycloak, the database has to be up and running. For such as scenario, I think, I should use [Argo Workflow](https://argoproj.github.io/docs/argo/readme.html).

My question is, how to trigger the ArgoCD, after the database is up and running through the Argo Workflow? Or how to combine Argo Workflow with ArgoCD?

Comment: Couldn't you just use something like the Keycloak Helm chart, which allows you to optionally enable the DB for you? That would eliminate the need for a workflow to spin up the server and keep everything in ArgoCD.

Comment: Could you please provide an example? How deploy multiple pod?

Comment: So I'm not super familiar with ArgoCD, but I understand it can [deploy Helm charts](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/helm/), and there is a [Keybase Helm chart with a DB option](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#prerequisites-details).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible without using Argo Workflow to spin up a Postgres server. ArgoCD supports multiple ways to deploy a "package" of resources that includes both Keycloack and Postgres.

For example, you could use [Keybase's Helm chart](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak#prerequisites-details) which optionally supports a Postgres component.

Then you can follow [ArgoCD's documentation on deploying Helm charts](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/helm/).

While Argo Workflows *does* help manage sequential tasks, those tasks are usually ephemeral - they execute once and disappear. For a more persistent Postgres server, you want to make it part of your deployment rather than a one-off task.